# Index on Multiple Date Fields

Tags: sql-server

I have a script that is heavily used. The primary part of the script, which if I remove, speeds up immensely, is:

```
WHERE
(
        DateTimeField1 IS NULL OR
        DateTimeField2 IS NULL OR
        DateTimeField3 IS NULL
) AND
DateTimeField4 IS NULL
```

If I exclude two of the three in the OR statement, it speeds up. Seems that since I am only checking if null, it should be really efficient.

What is the best way to either 1) index these fields or 2) speed up the where clause?

Comment: What's the reason you have 4 `datetime` fields?

Comment: The table contains fields that specify when certain actions take place. There are quite a number of datetime fields in this table.

Comment: Doesn't sound normalized to me. Try the answer below.

Comment: I use datetime fields as flags for certain actions/statuses in this table. Instead of just using a bit field. I have too many status fields to be using unions. I don't see how that would help. I suppose I could convert to bit. But that won't solve my problem now as a conversion takes time.

Comment: The solution is to normalize your table.

Comment: So how would you normalize these date fields?

Comment: Have an action/statuses table that records each action/status on its own row.

Comment: Already do that. However, when querying each of these, that would be a lot of joins. 10 DateTime fields, or 10 joins? Which would perform better?

Comment: You're doing the `JOIN`s wrong then. Anyway, 10 join's would perform better with what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest that you alter your table to have a computed column, something like:

```
alter table t add
ValidDates as ((case when DateTimeField1 is null then 'N' else 'Y' end) +
               (case when DateTimeField2 is null then 'N' else 'Y' end) +
               (case when DateTimeField3 is null then 'N' else 'Y' end) +
               (case when DateTimeField4 is null then 'N' else 'Y' end)
              )
```

Then create an index on the computed column:

```
create index t_validdates on t(validdates);
```

And then in your query, replace your `where` condition with:

```
where ValidDates in ('YYYY', 'YYNY', 'YNYY', 'YNNY', 'NYYY', 'NYNY', 'NNYY')
```

This is assuming that you will want to test various combinations of the NULLs.  If it is always what you have in the query, then you can make that condition the computed column instead.

Comment: I am going to try this further. It makes perfect sense. Kind of what I was looking for.

Comment: instead of letters Y and N maybe 1 and 0? Should evaluate faster during matching.

Comment: Created a calculated field as you mentioned, called it active, whereas if any field was null, active = 1. Then created the index. A count returned in 60 ms before, now returns in 0. Didn't seem to speed up my query much. This is a great solution though, and I will take this approach.

Answer (score 0):

try an index with included columns:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_datetimes on YourTable (DateTimeField4)
INCLUDE (DateTimeField1 , DateTimeField2 , DateTimeField3 );
```

this shoul find rows where DateTimeField4 is null quite fast. Then for each such row the OR for the other three can be done quickly. It isn't even all 3 that need to be checked in every row as per logic of OR the first one with a NULL will make the whole WHERE-clause true

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately didn't seem to make much of a difference.

Comment: did you test with all four and then with just two - the simplified version that worked faster?

Comment: Great concept. But the top three date fields will return less results than the fourth. Out of 200,000 records, the "or" part will return about 800, and then from there, the fourth will rule out about 10 or so.